# Firefox: set all cookies session-only, except specific ones?

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies

I'd like to have all cookies as **session-only**, **except** ones that I **whitelist**,
so that sites working with cookies only won't break but their cookies are still not retained, but on the other hand, cookies used for log-in won't be deleted between sessions.

I tried the custom setting of clearing all cookies when closing Firefox (under `Privacy > History > Custom settings`), combined with the cookie whitelist feature, but it seems the latter one is "inferior" to the former, that is, it clears even the whitelisted cookies.

I'd appreciate if you had a suggestion on how to achieve that in preferences. I'm using 
**Firefox 75.0**.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the *Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed* checkbox instead of the `Privacy > History > Custom settings > Clear all cookies` option. That will leave the cookies whitelisted intact.